# In Keras, why must the loss function be computed based upon the output of the neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

First of all, I realize from a methodological standpoint why your loss function must be dependent on the output of a neural network. This question comes more from an experiment I've been doing while trying to understand Keras and Tensorflow a bit better. Consider the following:

```
input_1 = Input((5,))
hidden_a = Dense(2)(input_1)
output = Dense(1)(hidden_a)

m3 = Model(input_1, output)

def myLoss (y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sum(hidden_a)                    # (A)
    #return K.sum(hidden_a) + 0*K.sum(y_pred) # (B)

m3.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=myLoss)

x = np.random.random(size=(10,5))
y = np.random.random(size=(10,1))

m3.fit(x,y, epochs=25)
```

This code induces:

```
ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

but it runs if you swap line `A` for line `B` despite the fact that nothing has changed numerically.

The former case seems like it should be perfectly fine to me. The computation graph is well defined and everything *should* be differentiable in terms of the loss. But it seems that Keras requires `y_pred` to be in the loss function somehow regardless of whether or not it has any effect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that it's a bit tricky. In fact, Keras does not need `y_pred` to be in the loss function. However, it needs that *all* trainable variables to be referenced in the loss function.

When you call `m3.fit()`, Keras will perform a gradient computation between your loss function and the trainable weights of your layers. If your loss function do not references the same elements that you have in the trainable_variables collection, some of the gradients computation operations will not be possible.

**So how to avoid it ?** Well, you could reference `y_pred`, even if doesn't do anything. Or you could freeze the layers that won't be impacted by the optimizer (as you don't compute their loss anyway)

So in your case, you just have to freeze your output layer :

```
output = Dense(1, trainable = False)(hidden_a)
```

Comment: I suppose I'm more confused about the nature of tensors in Keras. If I have a loss function that depends _only_ on `y_pred` and `y_true`, then that makes sense to me--calling the function links up a loss tensor to the output of the network. But if I include `hidden_a` in the loss, a tensor that does exist outside of the loss function itself, what happens? What if I call the model on a different input (eg `m3(different_input)`) so that there are now multiple tensors (I think Keras calls them "nodes" per layer)?